# Retrieving methods and attributes for "arcpy.Describe" function using "dir" - but returning empty list

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am extracting methods and attributes available for an object using different raster classes available in ArcGIS. While "Raster" and "RasterInfo" class returns the methods and attributes for the raster, "arcpy.Describe" returns empty list. Am i missing something ?

```
import arcpy
input_fc = r"C:/For_Template_Work/Raster_Try/LC08_L2SP_029031_20220315_20220322.tif"

desc = arcpy.Raster(input_fc)  
print (dir(desc))
print ("\n")

ras_info = arcpy.RasterInfo(input_fc)
print (dir(ras_info))
print ("\n")

ras_desc = arcpy.Describe(input_fc)
print (dir(ras_desc))
['RAT', '__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__iand__', '__ifloordiv__', '__ilshift__', '__imod__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__invert__', '__ior__', '__ipow__', '__irshift__', '__isub__', '__iter__', '__itruediv__', '__ixor__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__weakref__', '__xor__', '_repr_png_', 'addDimension', 'appendSlices', 'bandCount', 'bandNames', 'bands', 'blockSize', 'catalogPath', 'compressionType', 'exportImage', 'extent', 'format', 'functions', 'getBandProperty', 'getColormap', 'getDimensionAttributes', 'getDimensionNames', 'getDimensionValues', 'getHistograms', 'getProperty', 'getRasterBands', 'getRasterInfo', 'getStatistics', 'getVariableAttributes', 'hasRAT', 'hasTranspose', 'height', 'isInteger', 'isMultidimensional', 'isTemporary', 'maximum', 'mdinfo', 'mean', 'meanCellHeight', 'meanCellWidth', 'minimum', 'name', 'noDataValue', 'noDataValues', 'path', 'pixelType', 'properties', 'read', 'readOnly', 'removeVariables', 'renameBand', 'renameVariable', 'save', 'setBandProperty', 'setColormap', 'setHistograms', 'setProperty', 'setStatistics', 'setVariableAttributes', 'slices', 'spatialReference', 'standardDeviation', 'uncompressedSize', 'variableNames', 'variables', 'vectorize', 'width', 'write']


['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'fromJSONString', 'getBandCount', 'getBlockHeight', 'getBlockWidth', 'getCellSize', 'getExtent', 'getNoDataValues', 'getPixelType', 'getSpatialReference', 'setBandCount', 'setBlockHeight', 'setBlockWidth', 'setCellSize', 'setExtent', 'setNoDataValues', 'setPixelType', 'setSpatialReference', 'toJSONString']


[]
```

Comment: I think that it's because the describe object has methods from many different objects. A GeoTIFF file should implement dataset, raster dataset, band and maybe even table, each one having their own methods and properties, perhaps not something that dir can iterate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use arcpy.da.Describe(), however, this will return a dictionary so the dir function will give you the methods and properties for a dictionary only. But you can easily access the property names using

```
ras_desc = arcpy.da.Describe(input_fc)
print(list(ras_desc.keys()))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Is this method more efficient than using "arcpy.Describe()"

Comment: @joseph_k, in terms of performance the original `arcpy.Describe` will be faster to instantiate because it relies on late binding.  That is why `dir()` returns so little because not all of the methods are loaded upon creation of the object.  For quite a few ArcGIS objects, the difference between the old and new will be negligle, but there are definitely cases where using the newer `arcpy.da.Describe` will result in orders of magnitude slower instantiation.

Comment: Converting the dictionary keys to a list is not necessary.  The output from directly printing the keys is nearly identical to creating a list and printing the keys.